# Convert defined constant's name to int which is associated with it in C

Tags: c, winapi

I have some defined constants:

```
#define IDD_MAINDIALOG                  101
#define IDC_EXIT                        1001
#define IDC_START                       1002
#define IDC_STOP                        1003
#define IDC_STATE1                      1004
#define IDC_STATE2                      1005
#define IDC_STATE3                      1006
#define IDC_STATE4                      1007
#define IDC_STATE5                      1008
#define IDC_FORCE1                      1009
#define IDC_FORCE2                      1010
....
```

meaning corresponding cells of `Static Text` in my program

[image]

And I need to constantly change values in these cells. I think to do in with `SetDlgItemText`. But it needs the `int` value of changed control as a second parameter. I tried to do like this:

```
sprintf(forceId, "IDC_FORCE%d", philNum + 1);
sprintf(wisdomId, "IDC_WISDOM%d", philNum + 1);
...
SetDlgItemText(hWnd, (int)forceId, force);
SetDlgItemText(hWnd, (int)wisdomId, wisdom);
```

But the program displays nothing, and while tracing I found that I have `(int)forceId` and `(int)wisdomId` values about 11793000 instead of 1007 or something.

So, what is the correct way to convert defined constant's name into the `int` value which it is associated with?

I don't want to use exact names of controls to avoid copying of code, because I have many cells, and I also understand that in this case it is possible to use the numbers 1001, 1002, ... in a loop but I want to exclude crash of the program if some changes will be made (like deleting a cell with id `IDC_STATE3`).

Comment: `(int)forceId` is converting a pointer to a string into `int`, which is most definitely not what you might want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constant names don't exist at runtime, they are only meaningful to the preprocessor.  At runtime, only their numbers will exist.  Everywhere your code uses `IDC_FORCE1`, etc, they will be replaced with their actual numbers during the compiling process.

`SetDlgItemText()` takes a parent window and a child control ID as input.  You are trying to pass in a formatted string as the control ID.  That will not work.  Just pass in the actual control ID number as-is instead, eg:

```cpp
#define IDC_FORCE_BASE                  1009
#define IDC_FORCE1                      IDC_FORCE_BASE+0
#define IDC_FORCE2                      IDC_FORCE_BASE+1

...

SetDlgItemText(hWnd, IDC_FORCE_BASE + philNum, force);
```

Do the same with `IDC_STATE...`, `IDC_WISDOM...`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `forceId` and `wisdomId` are `char*`, so you are using the addresses of those strings.

Regardless, you won't have `IDC_STATE1` values at runtime, it will be `1004`

For things like that, I would manually arrange the IDs in a proper order, and just do calculations based on the first ID:

```
SetDlgItemText(hWnd, IDC_FORCE1 + philNum, force);
```

Comment: Ok, I understand my mistake. So is it impossible to compound a name of the defined constant of some "parts" (chars) ?

Comment: @Ilya please see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you, will try